# P3431 P0304 but engine does not feature cylinder deactivation?

Tags: dodge, misfire, p0300

2010 Dodge Grand caravan 3.8L (I think)
CEL light came on and codes pulled were p0304 p0300 and p3431 , I'm curious  as to what's up with the p3431. Looking it up on the typical obd sites say that it's a code for a cylinder deactivation feature. Could this code be related to my misfire?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that code could well be related to your misfire.

Codes can be thrown as they are related to the fault recorded and, sometimes, odd codes get recorded... I had a manual Golf which threw an automatic gearbox fault code...

Once the fault has been fixed, then related codes, once cleared, will stay cleared.

Comment: Just wait till you get a "cheap" scanner app where somebody entered the text of the messages by copying a list they found somewhere, and error code p0123 gets reported as "same as above".